# Variable behavior in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this weird case I can not explain:

```
@@test = 1234

def m
  puts @@test
end

class Test
  @@test = 5678
end

m
```

if I do not define 5678, then output is 1234.

if I do not define 1234, then undeclared variable error.

Now, if I define 1234, the output is 5678, why?

I am really confused by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I do not define 5678, then output is 1234.

This is because `@@test` is a class variable, which is shared between its class's children classes. You defined it on the top level, and the toplevel has the scope of the class `Object`, and method `m` becomes the *private* method of the `Object` class. So while you are calling `m` from the top level, you are getting the output as `1234`.

> Now, if I define 1234, the output is 5678,

As I said class variables are *shared*. `Test` by default is the child class of `Object`. And inside the `Test` you had modified the shared variable `@@test`. That's why now calling `m` is giving the current updated value of `@@test` which is `5678`.

> if I do not define 1234, then undeclared variable error.

Nothing wrong. If you try to use the class variable before defining them, you will get the exception as **uninitialized class variable @@test**.